# factory_girl linter failing because of ActionView::Template::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm in the process of working out the bugs for updating an app from rails 4.1 to rails 5. When I try to run my tests the factory_girl linter complains that some of the factories are invalid:

```
/Users/stephen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ssa/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/linter.rb:13:in `lint!': The following factories are invalid: (FactoryGirl::InvalidFactoryError)

* call_log - Undefined variable: "$green". (ActionView::Template::Error)
* sms_log - Undefined variable: "$green". (ActionView::Template::Error)
```

etc.

This is all factory girl really gives me for a stack trace. It tells me the where the linter is called but that is it. No indication where something might be going in the view. Is there a way for me to determine this? It seems like this is going to be very difficult to debug fi I don't know where it's coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having investigated by sitting right next to you, I am going to go out on a limb and say that the model has a callback that sends an email, which triggers the whole ActionView rendering, which apparently has some errors.

More proof that callbacks are bad - particularly ones that send emails.